# How to stop infinite loop programatically in java?

Tags: java

Here we are taking a java program as a input to the another java program.In case if the given program contains any infinite loop then I want to kill that particular process of a input program.Here in the code we have used threads also to halt the process but we are not getting any solution for this.

```
 public class JavaCompiler extends Thread {

    String path = "";
    String fname = "";
    String output = "";
    String totalPath = "";
    String s = null;
    String log = "";
    String errorfile = "";
    String ret = "";
    private String resultString = "";

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Entered RUN method");
        try {
            System.out.println("sleep Run Method");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(errorfile, true);
            System.out.println("sleep Run Method1");
            Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(totalPath);
            System.out.println("sleep Run Method2");
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getErrorStream()));
            System.out.println("Entered stderror");
            boolean error = false;
            log += "\n....\n";
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                error = true;
                fos.write(s.getBytes());
                System.out.println("Error Errorloop");
                ret = "errortrue";
                           }
            fos.close();
            if (error == false) {
                System.out.println("output loop");
                  output = runProcess(path, fname);
                ret = output;
            }
            if (output.equals("success")) {
                System.out.println("Output success loop");
                ret = "success";

            } else {
                System.out.println("Output false loop");
                  ret = "errortrue";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Message"+e.getMessage());
            ret = "error";
        }
    }

    public String javaProgram(String strFilePath, String filename) throws Exception {
        path = strFilePath;
        fname = filename;
        totalPath = "javac" + " " + strFilePath + "/" + fname + ".java";
        System.out.println("Total path" + totalPath);
        errorfile = strFilePath + "/" + fname + "_Error.txt";
      //  JavaCompiler j = new JavaCompiler();
       // j.start();
        start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //j.stop();

        System.out.println("Stopping run method");
        System.out.println("After sleep");
        System.out.println("Returing value=====" + ret);


        return ret;


    }

    private static String runProcess(String command, String filename) throws Exception {
        String path1 = "java" + " " + "-cp" + " " + command + "/" + " " + filename;
        System.out.println("Path" + path1);
        String filepath = command + "/" + filename + "_output.txt";
        System.out.println("filepath=============" + filepath);

        System.out.println("Entered");

        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path1);

        String s = printLines(filepath, pro.getInputStream());
        return s;
    }

    private static String printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
        String line = null;
        int count = 0;
        String strFilePath = name;
        System.out.println("NAME" + name);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath, false);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            fos.write(line.getBytes());
            System.out.println(name + " " + line);
//            count++;
//            if(count>10){
//                break;
//            }
        }



        fos.close();

        return "success";
    }
    /**
     * @return the resultString
     */
}
```

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an answer if you post less code. Show us a small example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path1)  

This process executes a java program, if this program contains any infinite loop I want to kill that process after specific time period.